Problem debezium jdbc-sink connector. Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException:
I have a problem that I can’t solve, I have a jdbc-sink
{
    "name": "business-acc",  
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",  
        "tasks.max": "1",  
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://host/my_db",  
        "connection.username": "debezium_user",  
        "connection.password": "debezium_pass",  
        "insert.mode": "upsert",  
        "delete.enabled": "true",  
        "primary.key.mode": "record_key",  
        "schema.evolution": "basic",  
        "database.time_zone": "UTC",  
        "topics": "accounts" 
    }
}

so it starts and works well but when it goes on for a while it crashes with an error

The task was FAILED! Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: JDBC sink connector failure Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to process a sink record Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: error executing work Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend. Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)

Has anyone encountered such a problem? I checked many options but nothing helps): perhaps you have encountered such a problem or you have an idea on how to solve it.
